# Change List of Algorithms font with KOMA-Script

Tags: fonts, table-of-contents, koma-script, algorithm2e

I would like to change the font for all table of contents entries to `\sffamily`. For the regular table of contents, I have achieved this by using:

```
\setkomafont{disposition}{\sffamily\bfseries}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntries[%
    entryformat=\sffamily,
    pagenumberformat=\sffamily
]{section}{section,subsection}
```

However, the entries in the List of Algorithms (`\listofalgorithms`) are unchanged by this.

I'm using `scrbook` and `algorithm2e`.

---

Full sample:

```
\documentclass{scrbook} 
\title{A Sample Thesis} 
\author{A.N. Other} 

\usepackage{algorithm2e}

\setkomafont{disposition}{\sffamily\bfseries}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntries[%
    entryformat=\sffamily,
    pagenumberformat=\sffamily
]{section}{section,subsection}

\begin{document} 
\maketitle 

\frontmatter 
\tableofcontents 
\listofalgorithms

\chapter{Abstract} 
This is the abstract 

\mainmatter 

\section{This is a section}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
Algorithm
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Table of contents uses `\sffamily` correctly:
[image]

List of algorithms is not impressed:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make it easier for others to help you by extending your code to a small compilable document.

Comment: @siracusa Added!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to declare `algocf` as a KOMA-Script »TOC Style Entry«:

```latex
\documentclass{scrbook} 
\title{A Sample Thesis} 
\author{A.N. Other} 

\usepackage{algorithm2e}

\setkomafont{disposition}{\sffamily\bfseries}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  level=1,
  indent=1.5em,
  numwidth=2.3em
]{default}{algocf}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntries[
  entryformat=\sffamily,
  pagenumberformat=\sffamily
]{default}{section,subsection,algocf}

\begin{document} 
\maketitle 
\frontmatter 
\tableofcontents 
\listofalgorithms

\chapter{Abstract} 
This is the abstract 

\mainmatter 
\section{This is a section}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\caption{An Algorithm}
Algorithm
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

---

Regarding the question in the comment below:

Package `listings` uses the entry level `lstlisting`. If `lstlisting` should get the same format as `algocf` use:

```latex
\DeclareTOCStyleEntries[% ...Entry replaced by ...Entries
  level=1,
  indent=1.5em,
  numwidth=2.3em
]{default}{algocf,lstlisting}% <- lstlisting added
\DeclareTOCStyleEntries[
  entryformat=\sffamily,
  pagenumberformat=\sffamily
]{default}{section,subsection,algocf,lstlisting}% lstlisting added
```

Example:

```latex
\documentclass{scrbook} 
\title{A Sample Thesis} 
\author{A.N. Other} 
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{scrhack}

\setkomafont{disposition}{\sffamily\bfseries}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntries[
  level=1,
  indent=1.5em,
  numwidth=2.3em
]{default}{algocf,lstlisting}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntries[
  entryformat=\sffamily,
  pagenumberformat=\sffamily
]{default}{section,subsection,algocf,lstlisting}

\begin{document} 
\maketitle 
\frontmatter 
\tableofcontents 
\listofalgorithms
\lstlistoflistings

\chapter{Abstract} 
This is the abstract 

\mainmatter 
\section{This is a section}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\caption{An Algorithm}
Algorithm
\end{algorithm}

\chapter{Code}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={A code example}]
Code
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Would you know how one would do the same for \lstlistoflistings? I've tried declaring a TOCStyleEntry for lstlistings and adding it to DeclareTOCStyleEntries, but sadly nothing happens.

Comment: See my updated answer.